# Module ImportError when launching python script in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, fedora

I use operating system commands in Matlab to launch python scripts. All was working fine till very recently, in fact I suspect that the problem comes with the recent upgrade of  Matlab to R2017b and Fedora to FC27.

The fact: If I launch a script python in a shell all is working fine. But if I launch the same script in Matlab, few  ImportError exception are raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1448, in __init__

    from xml.parsers import expat

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>

    from pyexpat import *

ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1451, in __init__

    import pyexpat as expat

ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data_1/IRM/amigo/src/IRMAGE_python_scripts/IRMAGE_report.py", line 1409, in <module>

    outFormat = 'png')

  File "/data_1/IRM/amigo/src/IRMAGE_python_modules/IRMAGE_reporting.py", line 1576, in plotPatVsRef

    bookRef = xlrd.open_workbook(refFile)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 422, in open_workbook

    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 784, in open_workbook_2007_xml

    ensure_elementtree_imported(verbosity, logfile)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 48, in ensure_elementtree_imported

    ET.iterparse(_dummy_stream)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1217, in iterparse

    pullparser = XMLPullParser(events=events, _parser=parser)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1256, in __init__

    self._parser = _parser or XMLParser(target=TreeBuilder())

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1454, in __init__

    "No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead"

ImportError: No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead
```

I am a little bit lost facing this problem since yesterday and I confess that I have no new idea to solve this problem … All idea, information, help about this problem will be very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the idea to check the shared object dependencies concerning the /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so that raised an ImportError exception !!!

in a shell:

```
% ldd /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd8f7c5000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff82fae8000)
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007ff82f588000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff82f369000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff82ef86000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff82ed82000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007ff82eb7f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff82e82a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff82ff2c000)
```

In Matlab:

```
! ldd /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeec596000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fcd2931e000)
        libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007fcd28dbe000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcd28b9f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcd287bc000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcd285b8000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fcd283b5000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcd28060000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcd29758000)
```

So it becomes evident that the problem comes from the libexpat.so.1 shared object that is older in the Matlab distrib (libexpat.so.1.5.0), than the one of the system (libexpat.so.1.6.7)!!!:

```
% ls -l /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64/libexpat.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     17 Feb 22 12:41 libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.5.0
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 182222 Jul 24  2017 libexpat.so.1.5.0
% ls -l /usr/lib64/libexpat.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     17 Nov  6 18:00 /usr/lib64/libexpat.so -> l    ibexpat.so.1.6.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     17 Nov  6 18:00 /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 206000 Nov  6 18:00 /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1.6.7
```

I fixed the problem by moving to an exclude directory the shared object of the Matlab distrib, to force to use the one of the system !!!

```
# cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/glnxa64
# mkdir exclude
# mv libexpat.so* exclude/
```

All is working fine now !!!

P.S. I experienced few other problems to running correctly Matlab after the upgrade of Matlab and Fedora that I  do not detail here. But if somebody have other problems with Matlab and FC26 or FC27 I can give upon request all the changes that I done (all are concerning shared object that are too old in the Matlab distrib !!!)